# How to create multiple connections to one host with elasticsearch-py?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I just found out that `elasticsearch-py(1.2.0)` only created one connection for each host you specifed.

As you can see in the source code, connections are created with mapping over `hosts`:

```
connections = map(_create_connection, hosts)
```

Do I need to implement my own `Transport` class if I want more than one connection per host?